# Determine whether A,B,C are pairwise independent and determine whether A,B,C are independant.

Tags: probability, independence

We started learning independence in class today and while trying to understand the concept I came across this question.

Let a sample space with four outcomes is given as 
Ω = {a1, a2, a3, a4} with
P({a1}) = P({a2}) = P({a3}) = P({a4}). Let A = {a1,a2}, B = {a2,a3}, C = {a3,a1}.
Determine whether A,B,C are pairwise independent.
Determine whether A,B,C are independent.

Any help on finding the solution will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

$A$,$B$, and $C$ are pairwise independent if all pairs of the events are themselves independent.  I.e. $A$ is independent to $B$, $A$ is independent to $C$, and $B$ is independent to $C$.

$A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)Pr(B)$ if and only if $Pr(A|B)=Pr(A)$ if and only if $Pr(B|A)=Pr(B)$

---

$A,B$ and $C$ are (*mutually*) independent if and only if $Pr(A\cap B\cap C)=Pr(A)Pr(B)Pr(C)$

---

Given the problem statement that $Pr(\{a_1\})=Pr(\{a_2\})=Pr(\{a_3\})=Pr(\{a_4\})$ and that these are the only outcomes available in our sample space, it follows that the probability of each outcome is $\frac{1}{4}$.

It follows that $Pr(A)=Pr(B)=Pr(C)=\frac{1}{2}$

Check the above conditions to see if $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)Pr(B)$ for each of the pairs of events.

Check the above conditions to see if $Pr(A\cap B\cap C)=Pr(A)Pr(B)Pr(C)$ for the events.

Comment: thank you for your response, here is what ive got: Pr(A∩B)=Pr(A)Pr(B) = 1/4, Pr(A∩C)=Pr(A)Pr(C)= 1/4, Pr(B∩C)=Pr(B)Pr(C) = 1/4 so Pr(A∩B), Pr(A∩C), Pr(B∩C) are pairwise independent. 
However Pr(A∩B∩C) does not equal Pr(A)Pr(B)Pr(C) so A,B,C are not independent or mutually independent. Right ?